# Disable pop-up when selecting text in Foxit-Reader

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

When selecting (e.g click and drag or double click a word) I get a pop-up, like so:

[image]

I find it quite annoying, and would like to disable it, but cannot find such a setting. Is this possible, or are there any tricks that I can use?
(Right now I tab `ALT` to remove it, which is annoying)

Foxit Version:  9.1.0.5096

Comment: You can also drag your cursor over it and off of it and it will disappear, I see no setting to disable this "feature". You might post your version of Foxit Reader.

Comment: I actually didn't know that, so that is actually a considerable help. Thanks.